# Why do I sometimes get a NullReferenceException in the BeginInvoke block?

Tags: c#, .net, invoke, begininvoke

So in my XXX.OnPropertyChanged() method I have:

```
public class XXX : IProperyNotifyChanged {
   Control itsCtrl;
   ...

   public void Init(Control ctrl) {
       itsCtrl = ctrl;
   }

   public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
        if (itsCtrl.InvokeRequired) {
            itsCtrl.BeginInvoke(() => {
              PropertyChanged(this, propertyName);
             });
        } else {
            PropertyChanged(this, propertyName);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I think this throws the following exception (rarely but happens more often now):

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232828
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm.WndProc(Message& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at DevExpress.Utils.Win.Hook.ControlWndHook.CallWindowProc(IntPtr pPrevProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at DevExpress.Utils.Win.Hook.ControlWndHook.WindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at Client.Program.Main() in C:\Client\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2147467261
       Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       Source=XXX
       StackTrace:
            at XXX.<>c__DisplayClass442_0.<OnPropertyChanged>b__0()
       InnerException:
```

I was just thinking. Is this happening because I am not copying variables properly like `this` and `propertyName` before calling `BeginInvoke`? Or is it something else? This happens so rarely that I am not sure how to reproduce it and I can't really get much from the stack trace. How would you fix this?

Comment: Is "itsCtrl" ever null? Add a null check before begin invoke and see if the problem goes away

Comment: itsCtrl is the MainForm. It can't ever be null.

Comment: @Denis That's not true.  When the form is loading, it can be `null`.  You are experiencing a race condition.

Comment: I usually get this error after the form has been running for awhile, not at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was just thinking. Is this happening because I am not copying variables properly like this and propertyName before calling BeginInvoke?

`this` is always inherently on the stack, and can't be assigned to something else, so it couldn't be set to null within the method. `propertyName` is local, so there can't be a race there.

`PropertyChanged` though isn't local, but obtained each time. When you do:

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
  PropertyChanged.BeginInvoke(…);
}
```

It acts like:

```
PropertyChangedEventHandler local1 = PropertyChanged; // Get value from property;
if (local1 != null)
{
  PropertyChangedEventHandler local2 = PropertyChanged; // Get value from property;
  local2.BeginInvoke(…);
}
```

There's an opportunity for `PropertyChanged` to be set to null in the meantime. **That's** what you want to make a copy of:

```
var propChanged = PropertyChanged;
if (propChanged != null)
{
  propChanged.BeginInvoke(…);
}
```

Now either `propChanged` will be null for the whole method's duration, or it won't be, and the race is gone.

Of indeed:

```
PropertyChanged?.BeginInvoke(…);
```

Comment: If I do PropertyChanged.BeginInvoke(). PropChanged is an event. What thread would that execute on? Suppose I call it from a non-GUI thread...

Comment: If you've a risk of that then redo the null check there (the use of null check syntax the other answer mentioned that I was sceptical of would indeed be good there)

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest making use of the null-conditional operator brought about by C# 6.0, if you can:

```
itsCtrl.InvokeRequired(...)   should be     itsCtrl?.InvokeRequired(...)
itsCtrl.BeginInvoke(...)      should be     itsCtrl?.BeginInvoke(...)
```

Unlike what you believe, while the form is loading, your control may be `null`, and so you're getting the exception from a race condition.

You should do the same to your PropertyChanged invocation:

```
PropertyChanged(...) should be  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)
```

This is thread-safe and will avoid the situation in which your check `if (PropertyChanged != null)` is no longer true due to some other thread changing it.

Comment: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(…)` would be good if the only thing depending on it being not null was whether that `Invoke` call was made, but here it isn't,

Comment: @JonHanna I'm not following you, could you elaborate?  Null-conditional is thread-safe and is exactly the same thing you wrote in your answer with assigning `PropertyChanged` to a local variable.

Comment: But the local only lasts for that one call. While equivalent to the abbreviated form in my answer, it's not equivalent to the question, because there's more going on within the `if` block than a single call to `BeginInvoke`

Comment: @JonHanna That's an issue with his design.  He can get rid of most of that code easily.  However, yes, I understand now what you mean.

Comment: I'm not following how the PropertyChanged event could be null. If no one is subscribed would raising the PropertyChanged event cause a null reference exception?